# What's the most efficient way to implement a simple ORM framework?

Tags: c#, database, orm, model

We have a simple database but which can contain thousands of rows.  We're trying to build a simple, lightweight ORM layer over it.  Think Dapper.  However, we're struggling to figure out how to ensure there is one and only ever one object per ID.

Consider the following data:

```
ID    Last       First
===== ========== =======
19    Donnely    Rick
20    Donovan    Sarah
21    Edwards    Sandra
```

Now consider the following SQL which is used to create Person objects in the ORM layer.

```
Select * From People Where ID = 20;

Select * From People Where LastName Like 'Don*'
```

In the first case, you'd get back 'Donovan' but in the second, you'd get back both 'Donovan' and 'Donnely'.  Since Donovan had already been returned, we want that instance to come back.

Now of course you would need some lookup by ID. That's easy.  What isn't is querying the database, returning rows, then determining that when creating objects you either need to create a new one or update an existing one (in case the data changed.)

The only thing I can think of is having the lookup have a method GetObjectById which either returns an existing object, or creates a new one, stores it, then returns that.  I assume it would also have to be based on weak references so they don't just 'hang around' in memory all the time.

```
// Assume the implementation stores the references weakly
public Person GetPersonById(int id)
{
    Person person = this[id]; // assume this returns null if not found

    if(person == null)
    {
        person = new Person(id);
        this[id] = person;
    }

    return person;
}
```

...or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: If it's readonly, why does it matter if you're creating duplicates or merely returning the original?

Comment: You're right. I left out relevant information. When I started to explain it, I realized that was superfluous to the question, so I removed all references to read-only as not to send people down the wrong path.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: In that case, your approach seems to be as good as you're going to get, as long as you're properly using weak-references. The other alternative is to have the user explicitly acquire and release rows

Comment: For lightweight ORM-like plugin, did you try LINQ to SQL ? Or even change your database to MongoDB. With MongoDB, you can have fun with fast and collection based database with SQL like query function. For rich ORM, you can use EntityFramework/NHibernate

Comment: All interesting answers, but off-topic. I'm not talking about where the data is stored. I'm talking about writing my own light-weight ORM that reuses existing objects rather than create duplicates. In other words, what is the basic storage *behind* NH and EF. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

One option for this is to use the [CSLA framework](http://www.cslanet.com/). It isn't an ORM, it is a "smart object" framework. It has simple, efficient change tracking of entities and collections of descendant entities. It also has several optional features, such as:

1. The ability to configure the application as a 2-tier or 3-tier application through configuration file.
2. Role based security.
3. Formalized Validation Rules (including support for validation attributes).
4. Formalized Business Rules (for synchronizing data between entities).
5. Several options for configuring the data tier, with support for any data persistence mechanism.
6. Support for virtually any UI framework in .NET.
7. Several object prototypes including readonly or read-write entities and collections.

The downside is that there is quite a learning curve to learn the framework (although there is good documentation), and it is not very DI or test framework friendly.

Comment: +1 for the info since it may help some, but again, I'm trying to do this simply and light-weight.  Consider it a coding learning exercise.  Again though, thanks for the heads-up on CSLA.

Comment: Great Info but only one thing...it is not that difficult to implement DI or make your business object testable...You can introduce DI by overriding default DataPortalActivator and implementing your custom DataPortalActivator...By doing this, you will have more control over business object instance creation hence you inject dependencies easily.

Comment: @Viru - Thanks for the tip. I will have to investigate that approach. Do you know of any documentation online that has a sample?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I myself learned in hard way but I got this link which gave me initial idea to work with DataPortalActivator. http://magenic.com/Blog/Post/43/Abstractions-in-CSLA

Comment: @Viru - Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, this approach is only slightly better than the approach I was using. I modified Jonny Bekkum's MEF implementation to use StructureMap property injection by injecting in the `DataPortal_OnDataPortalInvoke`, `Child_OnDataPortalInvoke`, and `OnDeserialized` for each object stereotype. Unfortunately, we are still stuck with property injection. However the approach does cut down on a lot of framework integration code, so it is definitely an improvement. It also solves a few of the UI integration and lifetime issues I was having.